# Identity for $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)^2$

Tags: summation

I have a function $$f(x)=(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2 + \dots + (x+n)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)^2$$
for some positive integer $n$. I started wondering if there is an equivalent expression for $f(x)$ that can be calculated more directly (efficiently).

I began by expanding some terms to look for a pattern.
$$
(x^2+2x+1) + (x^2+4x+4) + (x^2+6x+9) + (x^2+8x+16) + \dots 
$$
By regrouping the $x^2$, $x$, and constant terms, I can see that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}2kx + \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2
$$
for which I've found some identities to get
$$
f(x) = n x^2 + n(n+1)x + \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
$$
and simplifying some (attempting to make it computationally efficient)
$$
f(x) = n \left[ x^2 + (n+1)x + \frac{1}{6}(n+1)(2n+1) \right]
$$
$$
f(x) = n \left[ x^2 + (n+1) \left( x + \frac{2n+1}{6} \right) \right]
$$

> Is this a particular type of summation (maybe just exponential?), and if so is there a standard way to write it?
>   Along those lines, is there a more direct derivation than what I've attempted here, perhaps using an identity I don't know?

Comment: Seems pretty direct to me.

Comment: On your second question: let's call your last formula $g(x)$. You can verify a bit more easily that $f(0) = g(0)$ and $f'(x) = g'(x)$. Then $f(x) = g(x)$. [Can do with $f'' = g''$ also.]

Comment: That's straightforward enough as you have it. You could maybe calculate $f'(x)$ then integrate the linear function and determine the integration constant from $f(0)$ but I wouldn't call that any more *direct*.

Comment: @dxiv It sounds like you and user66081 are referring to the same approach.  Is there a name for it?

Comment: That's a direct consequence of the [Sum rule in differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation#Generalization_to_finite_sums). I am not aware of a special name for it.

Comment: Ah ok, got it.  Thanks @dxiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is just a second-degree polynomial, so its coefficients can be found by computing $f(0),\,f'(0),\,f''(0)$, where:
$$ f(0)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2,\qquad f'(0)=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k,\qquad f''(0)=2n$$
are associated with pretty well-known sums. Have a look at the [hockey stick identity](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity) and [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) to get an idea about computing $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$ through
$$ \sum_{k=m}^{M}\binom{k}{m}=\binom{M+1}{m+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Given the identity:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Write

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)^2 = \sum_{k=x+1}^{n+x}k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n+x}k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{x}k^2$$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)^2 = \frac{(n+x)(n+x+1)(2n+2x+1)}{6} - \frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}$$

Which reduces to:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)^2 = n \left[ x^2 + (n+1) \left( x + \frac{2n+1}{6} \right) \right]$$